# How to take data every column and row in excel and put another form using i macros

Tags: imacros

Pleas help me to How i can take data from excel sheet (every column and row ) 
Let suppose

```
        Column1                    Column 2
Row1  203-9996158-5745105         15505431376413                                                                                    
Row2  202-1824037-7498701         15505431376685
```

How can i get data from excel and put to another website

```
TAG POS=3 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://sliex.com/orders-v3/ref=xx_myo_dnav_xx?page=1 ATTR=* CONTENT=203-9996158-5745105
TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:https://sliex.com/orders-v3/ref=xx_myo_dnav_xx?page=1 ATTR=*
TAG POS=8 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Select<SP>an<SP>option
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:DPD
TAG POS=4 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=15505431376413
TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT=15505431376413
TAG POS=9 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=*
```

This is single manually code but i want all automation.. First take data first row when done then auto start next row 
Thanks

Comment: Yeah well, this is very "Basic" Functionality that you want, completely documented in the Wiki, + you even have 1 Demo-Macro doing exactly what you want, and you'll find 100's and 100's or maybe even 1000's of Examples on the iMacros (correct Spelling btw...) Forum... => Read a bit of the Documentation, I would say...

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Save excel table as into a comma-separated text (CSV) file.
> 2. Edit macros

```
SET !DATASOURCE filename.csv
SET !VAR1 {{!COL1}}
SET !VAR2 {{!COL2}}
TAG POS=3 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:https://sliex.com/orders-v3/ref=xx_myo_dnav_xx?page=1 ATTR=* CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:https://sliex.com/orders-v3/ref=xx_myo_dnav_xx?page=1 ATTR=*
TAG POS=8 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=*
TAG POS=4 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Select<SP>an<SP>option
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:DPD
TAG POS=4 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
TAG POS=5 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=* CONTENT={{!VAR2}}
TAG POS=9 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=*
```